# How do I discover peers in an Ubuntu VM in an Azure Service?

Tags: networking, azure, autodiscovery

I'm setting up a few Ubuntu 14.04 (LTS) virtual machines under an Azure Service (Availability Set). I'd like for each of these to be able to discover dynamically at least one other system in the local group so that they can initialize an etcd service on boot.

What approach would you take to do this?

Would it be best to simply try connecting to an etcd service on each address in the same netmask until I can connect to one? (Should work with IPv4 okay, but may be problematic in the future).

Don't want to expose this outside of the cluster for the service/vlan in question.

Answer (score 1):

Azure provides DNS for cloud services. Since you are using an availability set all your VMs are in a cloud service. Consequently, your VMs should be able to reach each other by hostname.

If your VM is in a VNET you have the additional option of configuring the VMs to have a [static IP address](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/04/22/static-internal-ip-address-for-virtual-machines/). Furthermore, VMs are typically allocated to sequentially increasing IP addresses in a subnet - e.g., 10.0.0.4, 10.0.05, etc.